# How do I install MongoDB on FreeDSB if the port was apparently removed?

Tags: mongodb, freebsd

Running `sudo pkg install mongodb` produces an error stating that no such package exists. I figured this is because it says on this website https://www.freshports.org/databases/mongodb/ that the MongoDB port has expired and has been removed. How do I get a version of MongoDB on my FreeBSD server now?

Comment: What FreeBSD version are you using? Also, are you using the latest or the quarterly branch for [pkg(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) (you may want to check in your [pkg.conf(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pkg.conf))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that every time you want to install a package you perform a pkg search

```
pkg search packagename
```

For MongoDB:

```
root@demo:/ # pkg search mongodb
mongodb32-3.2.11_2             Distributed document-oriented "NoSQL" database
mongodb32-tools-3.2.11         Tools for MongoDB
mongodb34-3.4.16               Distributed document-oriented "NoSQL" database
mongodb34-tools-3.4.9          Tools for MongoDB
mongodb36-3.6.6_2              Distributed document-oriented "NoSQL" database
mongodb36-tools-3.6.3          Tools for MongoDB
p5-Mojolicious-Plugin-Mongodb-1.16_1 Use MongoDB in Mojolicious
p5-MongoDB-2.0.1               Mongo Driver for Perl
php56-pecl-mongodb-1.5.2       PECL classes for MongoDB
php70-pecl-mongodb-1.5.2       PECL classes for MongoDB
php71-pecl-mongodb-1.5.2       PECL classes for MongoDB
php72-pecl-mongodb-1.5.2       PECL classes for MongoDB
py27-mtools-mongodb-1.2.3_2    Setup test environments; parse, filter and visualize MongoDB log files
py27-nagios-check_mongodb-0.1  Nagios plugin to check mongodb server
```

As you can see there are mongodb32, mongodb34 and mongodb36
You can then perform the following:

```
pkg install mongodb36-3.6.6_2
```

You could also install packages from ports but it's more time consuming and in the most cases is not necessary, unless you want to enable custom flags/modules to your mongodb installation.

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a note on the website you linked to that the MongoDB port was moved to [databases/mongodb34](https://www.freshports.org/databases/mongodb34/).

[Chapter 4.4. Using pkg for Binary Package Management](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/book.html#pkgng-intro) of the FreeBSD Handbook might help you to deal with the situation you describe (especially *4.4.9. Modifying Package Metadata*).

I am not sure, however, if there is an easy update path. I've never tried it.

Comment: Running `sudo pkg install mongodb36` produces `pkg-static: No packages available to install matching 'mongodb36' have been found in the repositories` although it says the 3.6 version is available.