# FreeBSD: upgrade MongoDB server from 2.6 to 3.0

Tags: mongodb

Running MongoDB v2.6 Server on FreeBSD operating system, I am looking for a way to upgrade the MongoDB version to at least v3.0. According to MongoDB website, I need to replace the binaries but I am not able to find appropriate download binaries for FreeBSD there [MongoDB download website](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community). Alternatively I had hoped, I could upgrade the binaries using pkg package manager but I don't know which command to use to upgrade to a specific version. I am looking for something like:

pseudocode:
sudo pkg upgrade mongod v3.03

I've been crawling the web for days now to find a download link for Freebsd binaries for Version 3.0x or right upgrade command using pkg package manager.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install MongoDB on FreeDSB if the port was apparently removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214130/how-do-i-install-mongodb-on-freedsb-if-the-port-was-apparently-removed)

Comment: Not quite - assuming I use a command like "pkg install mongodb36-3.6.6_2" as suggested in the linked question. Will this override the binaries of my existing v2.6 installation or will this rather install v3.6 in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is: using the command "pkg install mongodb36-3.6.6_2" as suggested in the link by Valijon will first deinstall a previous version and then install v3.6 of MongoDB Server. Just what I was looking for.